# No resource found that matches the given name @style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I'm receiving this error from Android Studio each time I try to build my project:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'editTextStyle' with value '@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText').

I've tried these items to no avail:

- Build -> Clean and then Build again
- Removing and then re-adding `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` from `build.gradle`.
- Reseting Git, even trashing the project and re-downloading entirely

Comment: Can you show your xmls?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your appcompat folder your system(C:.....\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat) ,

Open the **project.properties** file then change the value from

default 19 to 21

**target=android-21**

save the file and then refresh your project.

Then clean the project

Comment: Ah, I think I'm missing the app compact folder entirely. No idea what happened here... :/

Tip on how to re-add it?

Comment: Ok, I think something is hosed with the SDK Manager, perhaps... 
Android Studio -> Check For Updates gives "already have the latest"
Another way I need to do this?

Comment: tools -> android -> sdk manager and click on Launch stand alone sdk manager then update

Comment: Well, that didn't work, so I just reinstalled the entire Android studio. A bit nuclear, but meh? Thanks for your help point me in the right direction. :+1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access some resource from a `.xml` file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Go to App level "build.gradle" file and make sure the "buildToolsVersion" and "support:appcompat-v7" version are same. And also make sure "targetSdkVersion" and "compileSdkVersion" are same and doesn't differ from "buildToolsVersion" as well.
If that doesn't work then try to add latest version of Android for all these values mentioned above. Then Sync the project and Run.
Hope it'll work!